# Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 Read_Contacts and I don't have a write permission

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I try to build Retrieving a List of Contacts from android website,
https://android-doc.github.io/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html#Permissions
and I try to configure this to 31 target api.
I got this error

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #1
Process: com.example.contactlistandroid, PID: 15844
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{b4e47ee 15844:com.example.contactlistandroid/u0a160} (pid=15844, uid=10160) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS

here is my main activity

```
  /*
 * Copyright (C) 2013 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.contactlistandroid.ui;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.example.contactlistandroid.BuildConfig;
import com.example.contactlistandroid.R;
import com.example.contactlistandroid.util.Utils;

/**
 * FragmentActivity to hold the main {@link ContactsListFragment}. On larger screen devices which
 * can fit two panes also load {@link ContactDetailFragment}.
 */
public class ContactsListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ContactsListFragment.OnContactsInteractionListener {

    // Defines a tag for identifying log entries
    private static final String TAG = "ContactsListActivity";

    private ContactDetailFragment mContactDetailFragment;

    // If true, this is a larger screen device which fits two panes
    private boolean isTwoPaneLayout;

    // True if this activity instance is a search result view (used on pre-HC devices that load
    // search results in a separate instance of the activity rather than loading results in-line
    // as the query is typed.
    private boolean isSearchResultView = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Utils.enableStrictMode();
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set main content view. On smaller screen devices this is a single pane view with one
        // fragment. One larger screen devices this is a two pane view with two fragments.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Check if two pane bool is set based on resource directories
        isTwoPaneLayout = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.has_two_panes);

        // Check if this activity instance has been triggered as a result of a search query. This
        // will only happen on pre-HC OS versions as from HC onward search is carried out using
        // an ActionBar SearchView which carries out the search in-line without loading a new
        // Activity.
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {

            // Fetch query from intent and notify the fragment that it should display search
            // results instead of all contacts.
            String searchQuery = getIntent().getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            ContactsListFragment mContactsListFragment = (ContactsListFragment)
                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.contact_list);

            // This flag notes that the Activity is doing a search, and so the result will be
            // search results rather than all contacts. This prevents the Activity and Fragment
            // from trying to a search on search results.
            isSearchResultView = true;
            mContactsListFragment.setSearchQuery(searchQuery);

            // Set special title for search results
            String title = getString(R.string.contacts_list_search_results_title, searchQuery);
            setTitle(title);
        }

        if (isTwoPaneLayout) {
            // If two pane layout, locate the contact detail fragment
            mContactDetailFragment = (ContactDetailFragment)
                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.contact_detail);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This interface callback lets the main contacts list fragment notify
     * this activity that a contact has been selected.
     *
     * @param contactUri The contact Uri to the selected contact.
     */
    @Override
    public void onContactSelected(Uri contactUri) {
        if (isTwoPaneLayout && mContactDetailFragment != null) {
            // If two pane layout then update the detail fragment to show the selected contact
            mContactDetailFragment.setContact(contactUri);
        } else {
            // Otherwise single pane layout, start a new ContactDetailActivity with
            // the contact Uri
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ContactDetailActivity.class);
            intent.setData(contactUri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This interface callback lets the main contacts list fragment notify
     * this activity that a contact is no longer selected.
     */
    @Override
    public void onSelectionCleared() {
        if (isTwoPaneLayout && mContactDetailFragment != null) {
            mContactDetailFragment.setContact(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSearchRequested() {
        // Don't allow another search if this activity instance is already showing
        // search results. Only used pre-HC.
        return !isSearchResultView && super.onSearchRequested();
    }
}
```

mainfest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.contactlistandroid">
<!--
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
-->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ContactListAndroid"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.ContactsListActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Add intent-filter for search intent action and specify searchable configuration
                via meta-data tag. This allows this activity to receive search intents via the
                system hooks. In this sample this is only used on older OS versions (pre-Honeycomb)
                via the activity search dialog. See the Search API guide for more information:
                http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable_contacts" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.ContactDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/activity_contact_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.ContactsListActivity">
            <!-- Define hierarchical parent of this activity, both via the system
                 parentActivityName attribute (added in API Level 16) and via meta-data annotation.
                 This allows use of the support library NavUtils class in a way that works over
                 all Android versions. See the "Tasks and Back Stack" guide for more information:
                 http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html
            -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ui.ContactsListActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the permission and verify if it was allowed with a broadcast listnener I think

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: @NMZ Runtime permissions are checked with [`Context.checkSelfPermission(String permission)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#checkSelfPermission(java.lang.String)), not broadcast receivers.

Comment: Where do you think i need to put this permission?

Comment: before reading contact, check if permission is allowed, if it's not, use requestPermission. You can receive the user answer with a BroadCast Receiver